# Firefox add-ons href not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, href, add-on

**href in the context of firefox add-on not working**

I made a firefox add-on that inserts a button into a page, with a href attribute.Could anyone  tell me why the link is not working.I made the same with a chrome extension and everything works as I expected on chrome.The html inserted on page looks like this:

```html
<a class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-primary" 
   style="color: white; float: right;"   
   href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8HOfcYWZoo">Download MP3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in firefox and chrome, and everything is okay. Paste whole code or give a link where we can see problem, because problem is not in your above code.

Comment: The HTML code works fine. The issue is when I try to inject it into the current tab using my Firefox Add-on

Comment: @user1531371 How are you injecting it, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but here's how to add a link to a page from an addon:

`element` is the element that you want to append the link to (this case is on google homepage

```
var element = window.content.document.getElementById("gbqfw"); 
var htmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
var ins = document.createElementNS(htmlns, "a");

ins.className = "yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-primary";

// changed color to green to be visible on google homepage 
// since i don't have your css classes

ins.style="color: green; float: right;"; 
ins.href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8HOfcYWZoo";
ins.innerHTML = "Download MP3"

element.appendChild(ins);
```

Just tried it on google.com and it added a nice link to a Céline Dion song :D.